# ¨PnPJS Graph : how to list all members of a Group

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnp-js-core, pnpjs, graph-api

I am trying to get all members from O365 group using pnpjs graph. Following is the snippet:

```
import { graph } from "@pnp/graph";
import '@pnp/graph/groups';

const group = await graph.groups.getById("GUID")();
console.log("group", group);
console.log("members", group.members);
```

I am getting group object back and it has information related to group e,g Group name etc. But `group.members` is undefined.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the members, otherwise you'll get undefined.

`const group = await graph.groups.getById("GUID").expand("members")();`

Comment: it worked, thanks