# Trying to get all the members of an M365 group using SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx, typescript

I am trying to use the code here in order to get all the members in an M365 group.
[¨PnPJS Graph : how to list all members of a Group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283766/%C2%A8pnpjs-graph-how-to-list-all-members-of-a-group)

I am getting an error

Uncaught (in promise) Error: There is no Graph Client available, either set one using configuration or provide a valid SPFx Context.

```
export default class DepartmentPhotosWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IDepartmentPhotosWebPartProps> {

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {

    sp.setup({
    
    spfxContext: this.context
    
    });
    
    return super.onInit();
    
  }

  public async render(): Promise<void> {
    

    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${ styles.customWebParts }">
    
    ${await this.getGroupData()}
    </div>`;

    


      
  }

  protected async getGroupData(): Promise<string>
  {
    const group = await graph.groups.getById("guid").expand("members")();

    console.log('group:' + group);

    return "getGroupData!";
  }
```

Comment: Have you authenticated properly? https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/concepts/authentication/

Comment: You'll need to setup `graph` as well as `sp` with the context: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/getting-started/#using-both-pnpsp-and-pnpgraph-in-spfx

Comment: @Pete which version of PnP JS library are you using?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I get this error. Module '"@pnp/sp"' has no exported member 'spfi'. I am using ... "@pnp/graph": "^2.14.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.11.0",

Comment: @GaneshSanap From package.json "sp-pnp-js": "^3.0.10"

Comment: BTW https://me-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/AdminHome.aspx#/webApiPermissionManagement has Microsoft Graph Group.Read.All

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can get graph client using SPFx **context** object
- Below are sample code to get list of member from Office 365 group.

```
public async ListUserInGroup(guid: string): Promise<any> {
    const { context } = this.props;
    const client: MSGraphClientV3 = await context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient("3");
    const response: any = await client.api(`/groups/${guid}/members/microsoft.graph.user`)
      .header('ConsistencyLevel', 'eventual')
      .search('displayName:Pr')
      .select('displayName,id')
      .orderby('displayName')
      .get();

    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
```

- Refer below Microsoft docs
- [MSGraphClient in SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph)
- API documents

  [List members](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

Comment: Thanks Rajat. I was able to install import { MSGraphClientV3 } from '@microsoft/sp-http'; but I am getting an error on this line ... const { context } = this.props;     Error is "Property 'props' does not exist on type 'DepartmentPhotosWebPart'.ts(2339)"

Comment: you need to pass context as props from webpart.ts file to your webpart.

Comment: Sorry Rajat I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Remove const { context } = this.props; line from method and use this.context at place of context

Comment: Hi Rajat the code above works but it only returns the Id. The displayName is always null. Have you seen that before? Thanks P

Comment: value
: 
Array(15)
0
: 
displayName
: 
null
id
: 
"4d76a6e0-etc"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
1
: 
displayName
: 
null
id
: 
"9c2721bd-etc"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

Comment: As per documentation it should work. refer this docs -  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-4-use-searchand-odata-cast-to-get-user-membership-in-groups-with-display-names-that-contain-the-letters-pr-including-a-count-of-returned-objects